# Problema con GITHUB: No me carga las imagenes a mi pagina

Tags: html, css, github

Cuando veo mi pagina con live server desde mi vs code, funciona perfectamente, pero en github pages no se ven las imagenes, podrian ayudarme? gracias de antemano.

Repositorio : https://github.com/Lucianofitti/Clipboardlandingpage

La pagina: https://lucianofitti.github.io/Clipboardlandingpage/

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

estas usando referencias relativas a una esctructura de archivos,  src="/images/image-computer.png" pero la ubicacion de tu archivo seria https://github.com/Lucianofitti/Clipboardlandingpage/blob/main/images/image-computer.png, no es posible acceder usando la esctructura relativa (relative path), si quieres acceder a ellos debes consultar el url del archivo, pero te puedes enfrentar a problemas de acceso a github no se si te bloqueen el trafico.